# "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component" when i try to change state in useEffect()

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a material drawer component that, when the component mounts, needs to check the local storage and get the logged in user, and then put the name of the user in the template.

This is my component:

```
const PersistentDrawer = () => {

  const [userLogged, setUserLogged] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    setUserLogged(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')))
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    },[])
  const classes = drawerStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <AppBar
            position="fixed"
            className={clsx(classes.appBar, {
            [classes.appBarShift]: open,
            })}
        >        
            <Toolbar>
            <IconButton
                color="inherit"
                aria-label="open drawer"
                onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
                edge="start"
                className={clsx(classes.menuButton, open && classes.hide)}
            >
                <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
                Persistent drawer
            </Typography>
            </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <Drawer
            className={classes.drawer}
            variant="persistent"
            anchor="left"
            open={open}
            classes={{
            paper: classes.drawerPaper,
            }}
        >
            <img className={classes.logo} alt="Incca Sistemas" src="/assets/logo-incca.png"></img>          
            <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
        <Typography component="h6">{userLogged.login}</Typography>
            <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
                {theme.direction === 'ltr' ? <ChevronLeftIcon /> : <ChevronRightIcon />}
            </IconButton>
            </div>
            <Divider />
            <List>
            {['Inbox', 'Starred', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (
                <ListItem button key={text}>
                <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={text} />
                </ListItem>
            ))}
            </List>
            <Divider />
        </Drawer>
        <main
            className={clsx(classes.content, {
            [classes.contentShift]: open,
            })}
        >
        </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PersistentDrawer
```

I'm receiving:

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is
>   a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix,
>   cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup
>   function.

How I can fix this?

Comment: Which update state call results in this error, if you could tell?

Comment: I am pretty new to react, but could it be that your component is rendered before useEffect had time to finish, and that is why it is happening? Per their docs regarding life cylce `The componentDidMount() method runs after the component output has been rendered to the DOM.`. I know that useEffect is supposed to be similar in nature

Comment: @veroneseWithS problem could be localStorage.getItem() please check if you are getting js object after JSON.parse

Comment: seems the problem is in my root application

Comment: But why do you use effect to basically get initial state? It all looks like you could simply do `const [userLogged, setUserLogged] = useState(() => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')))` This won't cause additional rerender.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `useEffect` to be as follows:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let neverMind = false;

  const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'))

  if(!neverMind) setUserLogged(currentUser)
  return () => ( neverMind = true);
},[])
```

Somehow your component is being unmounted, but even though it is unmounted - you are still trying to update its state. To avoid this, set a flag that will let you know when the component is unmounted (in the function being returned) and only update the state if the flag has not changed.

For another example of how the "cleanup function" is used, see the React docs - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1

Here is a link to Dan Abramov's answer to this question - https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14369#issuecomment-468267798

Answer (score 0):

**Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.**

This error occurs when an attempt is made to change a component that does not exist yet.

This is very often a result of parallel initializations (async) of components.

**For Example:**
Suppose that two components A, B are both initialized asynchronously in lines 1, 2. In line 3, if Component A tries to update Component B, then there is a likelihood that the component B (line2) did not get created by the time line 3 (update to B) got executed.

In such a case, the above error will be reported.

**How to fix?**
Identify and change the async code blocks or functions to make sure that no update is attempted on a component before it gets created.